# Coding in non-ASCII languages

Tags: c#, .net, unicode

Alright, I found this strikingly odd to me but in C#, you can actually write your source code in a different language. I've wrote an example source code in Korean to illustrate my point:

```
namespace 대한민국 {
    public class 학생 {
        public string 이름 { get; private set; }
        public string 좌우명 { get; private set; }

        public 학생(string 이름, string 좌우명) {
            this.이름 = 이름;
            this.좌우명 = 좌우명;
        }
    }
    public class 대학교 {
        private List<학생> 재학생목록 = new List<학생>();

        public void 입학(학생 입학생) {
            재학생목록.Add(입학생);
        }

        public void 재학생출력() {
            foreach (학생 선택된학생 in 재학생목록) {
                Console.WriteLine("이름: {0}", 선택된학생.이름);
                Console.WriteLine("좌우명: {0}", 선택된학생.좌우명);
            }
        }
    }
    public class 프로그램 {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            대학교 스쿨오브헬 = new 대학교();
            스쿨오브헬.입학(new 학생("전땅끄", "본인은 단돈 29만원과 땅끄로 이 신성하고 거룩한 국가의 민주주의를 발전시켰소"));
            스쿨오브헬.입학(new 학생("이피카츄", "여러분 이거 다 거짓말인거 아시죠!!!"));
            스쿨오브헬.입학(new 학생("빵상아줌마", "빵빵 똥똥똥똥 땅땅 따라라라라~~~"));

            스쿨오브헬.재학생출력();
        }
    }
}
```

The above code compiles and gives you a valid output.

With the exception of keywords, you could actually write your source code in languages other than English. Of course, this is highly impractical and nobody would do this.

My question is the following:

- Is this a C# feature or a Visual Studio feature? (I couldn't get a similar program to work in C++ under Visual Studio 2010)
- What is the performance impact? (I would readily assume almost none, but wasn't sure if they did any kind of crazy conversion for allowing non-ASCII characters for coding)
- What was the reason for implementing this feature?

Comment: It isn't impractical if you (meaning: all developers on the project) *speak* those languages. I've seen code with class-names and member-names written in non-English. Not a problem in the least.

Comment: @MarcGravell Oddly enough, as an ESL speaker, I tend to frown on not-English in code. (English has a few practical advantages for programming, not the least of which is the near-complete lack of noun declension. This makes the "sentences" that statements form violate grammar much less than in some other languages.)

Comment: @MarcGravell not entirely. Because the keywords (and available library methods, etc) are English, using non-English class names and member names really 'breaks' the flow of reading the code, even if you speak the language used.

Comment: @Bart it could be argued that `protected`, `virtual`, `override`, `static` etc aren't really part of regular English either (at least, not in the way they apply to programming) - they are just "magic tokens that do things"

Comment: What was the reason for implementing this feature: to give developers a guarantee against outsourcing - LOL (just kidding)

Comment: The biggest issue with this practice is that posting this code on SO will not lead to many/quick answers, as most users on SO will need to enquire as to the meaning of the different symbols.

Comment: @MarcGravell for those keywords yes, but what about `foreach` and `while` ? And the .NET class, method and attribute names?

Comment: @Oded true, but *obviously* every poster on SO is going to reduce their problem to a simplified, minimalist example that shows just the concepts necessary for the problem, so it can be renamed at that point (goes away chuckling)

Comment: @Bart heh, maybe - then, what's a little cognitive dissonance between friends, eh? maybe the intent is to hasten a psychotic episode in the unwary...

Comment: @MarcGravell - feature request: can the SO team please implement a multi-lingual dictionary that will translate all foreign variable names to the corresponding English variable names?

Comment: @BartFriederichs It's actually fairly common for most (non-English-speaking) programmers I know to drop into and out of English when discussing code. I've never heard a German-speaking programmer use the words "Faser" or "Muster" when they mean "threads" or "patterns". This would imply that they really associate the English word with the programming concept.

Comment: @millimoose `fenetre.Ouvrir();`

Comment: @millimoose I am a non-native English programming (Dutch) and find it extremely annoying to read code that has Dutch variable names. But I guess it could be a matter of taste.

Comment: Its not uncommon for people to use their native tongue when naming variables..

Comment: @BugFinder like `for(int ı = 0; ı < 10; ı++) {...}`?

Comment: @BartFriederichs Oh, my argument cuts both ways there. It also means those programmers might *prefer* the English words for programming concepts, so using native words for them will, paradoxically, be jarring. For what it's worth, I'm on your side with this, as are most codebases I've worked on. But switching languages "mid-sentence" in and of itself isn't the reason why I find native language identifiers jarring. As opposed to the grammar "not working", or being more familiar with the English terms for e.g. design patterns - that is, using the wrong language for the wrong concept.

Comment: I don't know about other languages but it is highly impractical for Korean. You have to toggle the English/Korean key whenever you want to switch languages and not only is this prone to typos, it results in more unnecessary typing a programmer could've easily avoided by sticking to English.

Comment: @l46kok That's a good point actually. Keyboard layouts that aren't the "standard" US one tend to be generally awful for curly-brace languages. Another interesting consequence of this all is that, say, the VS documentation in German is amusing in very... German ways. ("Web-Benutzersteuerelement" is a fantastic word.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Both the C# specification and the CLI specification permit this.

The C# standard says that

> A source file is an ordered sequence of Unicode characters.

and

> An identifier in a conforming program must be in the canonical format
>   defined by Unicode Normalization Form C, as defined by Unicode
>   Standard Annex 15. The behavior when encountering an identifier not in
>   Normalization Form C is implementation-defined; however, a diagnostic
>   is not required.

The ECMA CLI standard has this to say:

> ### I.8.5 Naming
>
> Names are given to entities of the type system so that they can be referred to by other
>   parts of the type system or by the implementations of the types. Types, fields, methods,
>   properties, and events have names. With respect to the type system, values, locals, and
>   parameters do not have names. An entity of the type system is given a single name (e.g.,
>   there is only one name for a type).
>
> #### I.8.5.1 Valid names
>
> All name comparisons are done on a byte-by-byte (i.e., case sensitive, locale-
>   independent, also known as code-point comparison) basis. Where names are used to access
>   built-in VES-supplied functionality (e.g., the class initialization method) there is
>   always an accompanying indication on the definition so as not to build in any set of
>   reserved names.

Important passage follows:

> **CLS Rule 4:** Assemblies shall follow Annex 7 of Technical Report 15 of the Unicode
>   Standard 3.0 governing the set of characters permitted to start and be included in
>   identifiers, available online at http://www.unicode.org/unicode/reports/tr15/tr15-18.html
>   Identifiers shall be in the canonical format defined by Unicode Normalization Form C.
>   For CLS purposes, two identifiers are the same if their lowercase mappings (as specified
>   by the Unicode locale-insensitive, one-to-one lowercase mappings) are the same. That is,
>   for two identifiers to be considered different under the CLS they shall differ in more
>   than simply their case. However, in order to override an inherited definition the CLI
>   requires the precise encoding of the original declaration be used.
>
> [Note: 
>   CLS (consumer): Need not consume types that violate CLS Rule 4, but shall have a
>   mechanism to allow access to named items that use one of its own keywords as the name. 
>   CLS (extender): Need not create types that violate CLS Rule 4.  Shall provide a mechanism
>   for defining new names that obey these rules, but are the same as a keyword in the
>   language. 
>   CLS (framework): Shall not export types that violate CLS Rule 4.  Should avoid the use of 
>   names that are commonly used as keywords in programming languages.

2) There should be no performance impact whatsoever. The CLI rules state that matching of names has to be done using the Unicode locale-insensitive mappings, which means that when two names need to be compared there has to be a conversion to a sequence of Unicode code points. **If** the compiler or runtime chooses to keep this information in a variable-length encoding such as UTF-8 and convert to code points on the fly then theoretically there would be some performance difference; practically I do not expect any implementation to do this, or the performance difference to be measurable if they did.

Note that CLS rule 4 says that "in order to override an inherited definition the CLI requires the precise encoding of the original declaration be used", which does place a specific restriction when overriding names. But since this is not a universal requirement, the "convert everything to code points before comparing" has to be implemented anyway.

3) Again, it is in the CLI specification so the language has to do it.

Comment: Your explanation for #3 is somewhat of a tautology. The CLI spec, C# spec, and C# compiler are all controlled by Microsoft and a few partners, so it's not like they weren't free to do otherwise. (Unlike C++ which I imagine isn't nearly as tied to a specific implementation vendor.)

Comment: @millimoose: The CLI spec is controlled by [ECMA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ecma_International). Also, there are other languages that target the CLI in addition to C# such as [boo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boo_(programming_language)); this argument applies to all of them.

Comment: The CLI spec was submitted to ECMA for standardisation, it wasn't developed by a working group at ECMA. The timing alone makes the latter impossible - wiki says the submission happened in mid-2000, by which time .NET was nearing beta status, and the CLI must have been in the works for years by then. For all practical intents and purposes Microsoft is the party which specified the CLI, and was free to decide what to allow in identifiers. I'd also argue the distinction between C# and CLI is artificial in this case, seeing as the two were created in concert.

Answer (score 5):

1: it is in the C# language specification, so: C#

2: none whatsoever; parsers don't really care much whether something is `Fred` vs `프로그램`; neither is significant to the compiler

3: because not all developers speak English (or: latin languages) as their primary language. It could well be that `프로그램` expresses the intention of the class very readily and meaningfully for the developers working on that project

Comment: For number 3, I'd rather say that this is not "implementing a feature", but "not removing a feature". C# native character set is Unicode, not ASCII, so there is no reason to treat characters above ASCII 127 differently, as ASCII-based languages do.